# Maven : mvn install command of large multi layer maven project unmappable character for encoding UTF8

Tags: linux, docker, maven, java-8

So i have this  problem with a multi layer maven project where when compiling it there s a module which is the most important one that s throwing many errors concerning utf8 here s a sample :
[utf8 unmapable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAhww.png) Do note that there are so many files so i can not change each character manually. I am on linux and this is a java8 project. It seems like the character at question is supposed to be " é " which is actually mappable on utf8 and when i tried to change one manually it still did not work and turned to " ? " . I really need help with this so i can compile it for the sake of my docker build.

. It seems like the character at question is supposed to be " é " which is actually mappable on utf8 and when i tried to change one manually it still did not work and turned to " ? " . I really need help with this so i can compile it for the sake of my docker build.

Comment: An utf8 character in File name? I would try to change that first... second why doing tests within productive code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.